# Glue sticks for print bed

Tags: abs, pla, fdm, adhesion

I would like to get a green tombow PITS adhesive stick. On Rakuten, it costs \$1 (USD). On my 3d printer's (XYZ) retailer's site, it costs \$20 (USD). Due to the costs and the fact that Rakuten does not ship to my country, I need an alternative. I am currently using Davinci 1.0 for my bed, which I believe is a glass bed. So, my questions are:

1. What glue is best for PLA plastic?
2. What glue is best for ABS plastic?
3. Is there a glue that functions with both types of plastic?

Comment: The glue sticks I saw in use were normal office supply sticks. So probably optimized to glue paper ;-) So I would recommend to use whatever your local office supply store has. You can also try hairspray.

Comment: @LarsPötter hairspray is ok but it sprays (spread) around. paper glue is way better as it can be applied on exact place on the bed.

Comment: @MithunKalan please refrain from using phrases like *What is the best...*. These types of questions typically fall under the category of **[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)**. Thank you and welcome to 3D Printing SE!

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Matt - PVA glues work perfect for both filaments.
It works well because it's softening temperature is between 45..85C so it's more or less temperature of HB.

Advantages:

- cheap
- easy to apply on HB
- can be applied on cold as same as on hot HB
- sticks model very well
- non toxic, no solvent, odorless
- easy to wash (from HB) (just wash it under water or scrape with sharp tool)
- works very well even with old and dry layer of glue

Disadvantages:

- quite hard to detach model (I use paper knife)
- first layer is not glass-perfect
- after detaching, model is a bit sticky (first layer)

I use Scotch Glue Stick by 3M.

Comment: This answer focuses on one specific type of glue, while there are countless ones that work. A "these types of glues work"-type answer would be significantly more valuable than this answer, which is essentially a product endorsement/review. (Like the one given by Matt, except a bit more detailed).

Comment: @TomvanderZanden you are absolutely right! But isn't it what Mithun Kalan was asking for? I'll edit my answer of course to make it more general.

Answer (score 2):

I use glue Sticks from Staples. It works. Anything else is over thinking :-)
I use it daily on PLA and ABS on 3 out of 5 printers. Printed 5 lbs this week in plastic so far.

Following my flashforge creator pros use this amazing mat, that even after months of use still work great (so long as I clean it with alcohol every so)

Some use hairspray. Tried it, mix results, got sick of breathing the stuff in. Also it wont work on both plastics as gluesticks do.

Answer (score 0):

Most PVA glue works well for both (Poly Vinyl Acetate).
There are different brands in every country.

Comment: Are you able to elaborate a bit more on the glue and what makes it a good choice?